# Is literal a special form value constructor?

Tags: haskell

with

```
data ListType = List Int Int Int deriving(Show)
```

`[1, 2, 3]` and `List 1 2 3`, can both get a list which contains one to three, can I regard literal as a special form of value constructor?

Not just limits in Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I regard literal as a special form of value constructor?

Basically, yes. Do note, however, that your `ListType` is not a list; it is (equivalent to) a tuple. Values of a list type may hold any number of elements, while `ListType` values can hold only three. Back to your question, though: `[1, 2, 3]` is indeed syntax sugar for `1 : 2 : 3 : []`, in which the `(:)` and `[]` constructors appear explicitly. Weren't it for the sugar and other syntactical details, a definition for the list type might be:

```
data [] a = [] | (:) a ([] a)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "literal", but the *List* data type that you defined above is actually not a conventional Haskell list. For one, your "List" has a fixed number of elements (3), while a Haskell list can contain from zero to an infinite number of elements. Your type is also specialized to the type Int, while Haskell lists can contain any type of elements, as long as all elements are of the same type. And, besides, Haskell lists are instances of a number of typeclasses (Functors, Monoids, Monads, etc.).

Haskell lists are a recursive data type and a possible constructor for them  would be:

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a) deriving Show
```

You could use this constructor as:

```
Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Empty))
```

Of course, it would be far more practical to use the built-in data type and build your list as:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Also, what do you really mean by "limits in Haskell"?

Answer (score 2):

Haskell allows a custom syntax for lists, such as

```
[1,2,3]
```

this is just a syntactic shortcut for

```
1 : 2 : 3 : []
```

which is another syntactic shortcut for

```
(:) 1 ((:) 2 ((:) 3 []))
```

Above, `(:)` and `[]` are data constructors.

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
[]  :: [a]
```

Keep in mind that the special syntax applies only to standard lists, not to user defined types. You can get something vaguely similar with e.g.

```
data MyList a = Nil | a :+ MyList a
```

and then using the `:+` value constructor in an infix way:

```
1 :+ 2 :+ 3 :+ Nil
```

Still, no `[1,2,3]` syntax for this type.